# In python, how can i duplicate raw input?

Tags: python-2.7

```
string1 = raw_input("input string?")
inten = raw_input("input positive intenger?")
print "multiplication : ", string1*inten
```

it said "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type `str` "

if i put `herb` and `5`
i want to get herbherbherbherbherb

PLZ Help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

You would want to

1. Convert inten to a number type
2. Iterate that many times and add to a string

An example would be as follows:

```
result = ''
// Cast string to int type before iteration here
for n in xrange(int(inten))
    result += inten
print result
```

There are a lot more/efficient ways of string concatenation you might want to check out here
https://waymoot.org/home/python_string/

Do try to format your code when you ask a question next time--It really takes literally 1 minute to learn the formatting

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATED

```
string1 = input("input string?")
intin = "test"

inten = int(input("input positive intenger?"))
i = 0
out = ""
while i < inten:
    out += string1
    i += 1
print (out)
```

I have used a while loop to print it the number of times that you input.

Note: The code will not work if you enter a string into the int... You can fix this, however I was unable to.

See an example here:
https://repl.it/BzfJ/23

Comment: your code said
herb(enter)
herb(enter)
herb(enter)
herb(enter)
herb   that's not what i want to know. But I appreciated your help anyway.

Comment: Well what do you want to know

Comment: Please note it is not fool proof... It will not work if you enter a string into the integer value

Comment: Ok, well I'm glad it works... If you think my answer best answers your question, please press the checkmark becide my answer to say "Yup this answer answered my question" If you liked my answer and think it is a quality answer, consider pressing the up arrow beside my answer to give me some reputation on the site. Thanks a ton, good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

you (almost) did it correctly!!!

you just forgot to add int... :)

```
string1 = raw_input("input string?")
inten = int(raw_input("input positive intenger?")) 
print "multiplication : ", string1*inten
```

this seems easier than for/while

but you may want to check that the second input is a string (with `str1.isdigit()`)